# Flask выдает ошибку. BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'id'

Tags: python, база-данных, flask

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня сейчас учебная практика в колледже, и препод сказал заполнить БД MySQL через страницу, написанную на Flask. Она открывается, но когда я заполняю форму, выскакивает сообщение об ошибке:

[image]

Где она может быть? Вот код на Python Flask.

```
import MySQLdb 
import pymysql
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from pymysql import cursors

AllLogin = []
app = Flask(__name__ , template_folder = 'templates')
db = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',password='12002-tnA',db='studentsworks',charset='utf8') #,user_unicode='True')
print("Connect OK")
cursor1 = db.cursor(cursors.DictCursor)
cur  = db.cursor()
Query = " Select name from tbl_employer "
cur.execute(Query)
AllLogin = cur.fetchall()
print('записи таблицы {} \n'. format(AllLogin))
for h in range(0, len(AllLogin)):
    print('Очередной логин {} \n'. format(AllLogin[h][0]))


@app.route('/input', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])                     
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        prizn = True
        ID = request.form['id']
        ENTERPRISE = request.form['enterprise']
        LASTNAME = request.form['lastname']
        NAME = request.form['name']
        PATRONYMIC = request.form['patronymic']
        POST = request.form['post']
        PHONE = request.form['phone']
        EMAIL = request.form['email']
        PROBLEMS = request.form['problems']
        sql = """ INSERT INTO tbl_employer(id, enterprise, lastname, name, patronymic, post, phone, email, problems) 
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """
        cur.execute (sql, (ID, ENTERPRISE, LASTNAME, NAME, 
PATRONYMIC, POST, PHONE, EMAIL, PROBLEMS))
        db.commit()
        res1 = cursor1.fetchall()  
# Помещаем результат чтения в список res1
        print (res1)               
# Печать всего списка
        return render_template('tbl_employers_2.html', results = res1)
    return render_template('tbl_employers_2.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, host = '127.0.0.1' )
```

Заранее благодарю,

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что в отправленной форме нет поля id. Я думаю имеет смысл добавить в вопрос html отправляемой формы.

Comment: имею такую же проблему, как решил в конечном итоге?